# Serverless lambda function failes in react with CORS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, axios, serverless-framework

Hi all I have written a serverless lambda API using API gateway, the API works as I expect it to do so while i use POSTMAN. the api used PATCH method to update a record in dynamoDB. I have then implemented axios in my in my React app to make the call to my API. The call fails due to CORS fine, i went over to API gateway and i enabled CORS for that end point by pressing on to the method PATCH going into Method Response and Integration Method added all the response headders

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers      
Access-Control-Allow-Origin   
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials      
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
```

deployed the API and does not work. I then tried in my serverless.yml to add `cors: true` and deploy this didnt work either.

Here is my cod:

Serverless.yml:

```
  setBookVotes:
handler: src/handlers/setBookVotes.handler
events:
  - http:
      method: PATCH
      path: /book/{id}/vote
```

React:

```
    export const updateVoteCount = (id, vote) => {
  return axios.patch(`book/${id}`, {
    vote: vote,
  });
};
```

Lambda:

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import middy from "@middy/core";
import httpJsonBodyParser from "@middy/http-json-body-parser";
import httpEventNormalizer from "@middy/http-event-normalizer";
import httpErrorHandler from "@middy/http-event-normalizer";

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

async function setBookVotes(event, context) {
  const { id } = event.pathParameters;
  const { vote } = event.body;

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.BOOK_TABLE_NAME,
    Key: { id },
    UpdateExpression: "set vote = vote + :vote",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":vote": vote,
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
  };

  let updatedVotes;

  try {
    const result = await dynamodb.update(params).promise();
    updatedVotes = result.Attributes;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new createError.InternalServerError(error);
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(updatedVotes),
  };
}

export const handler = middy(setBookVotes)
  .use(httpJsonBodyParser())
  .use(httpEventNormalizer())
  .use(httpErrorHandler());
```

Comment: If you are passing AWS STS token as authentication after enabling `IAM_Auth` enable to Yes.

Comment: @aviboy2006 could explain it a bit more, i mean if i use sts token to access a API does it mean i will not have to worry about cors? because it will be treated as a trusted end point? thx

Comment: Generally this error comes because `IAM_AUTH` is enabled and token is expire while passing in API gateway under header.